# change color of uiimageview in a empty array by pressing on it

Tags: swift, tags, imageview, append, user-interaction

My swift code below has a button and when touch places a imageview on the viewcontroller. The only thing I want to do is when a individual imageview not all of the imageview just the one select is touch I would like to change the color from purple to blue only if touched and one at a time.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var count: Int = 0
   var ht = -90
   var ww = 80
   var moveCounter = 0
   var counter = 0
   var arrTextFields = [UIImageView]()
   var b7 = UIButton()


   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       [b7].forEach {
           $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           view.addSubview($0)
           $0.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
       }

       b7.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y + 200, width: 70, height: 40)
       b7.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addBOx), for: .touchUpInside)

   }

   //func that adds imageview.
   @objc func addBOx() {

       let subview = UIImageView()

       subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
       arrTextFields.append(subview)
       view.addSubview(subview)


       subview.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 0, y: view.bounds.midY + CGFloat(ht), width: CGFloat(ww), height: 35)


       subview.backgroundColor = .purple
       subview.tag = count

       count += 1
       ht += 50
       arrTextFields.append(subview)



   }}
```

Comment: can you attach screenshots ??, I am not properly understanding your question what do you want to do on the _ButtonClick_ ????

Comment: buttonClick is when func addBoX IS called. That func adds image views to the view controller. When one of those image views is click on the color should change of that one from purple to blue. I will try to add some images soon.

Comment: @NayanDave added a screenshot of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already set the `isUserInteractionEnabled` property of the image view to `true`. To respond to touch events, create a [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer) and add it to the image view like so:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageViewTapped))
subview.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

Then inside of the `imageViewTapped` method you can extract the image view from the sender argument:

```
@objc func imageViewTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let imageView = sender.view as? UIImageView {
        // Change the imageView's background here
    }
}
```